# Python get index of class list on condition

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
class Order:
    def __init__(self, amount, orderId):
        self.orderId = orderId
        self.amount = amount 
        

n = 5
amounts = np.random.randint(low=8, high=20, size=n)
orderIds = np.arange(n)

orders = [Order(amounts[i],orderIds[i]) for i in range(n)]
```

And I would like to get a list of orderId for all orderId when the cumulative sum of amount of the sorted list if above some threshold.

Example:

```
orderIds = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
amounts = [15, 18, 19, 16, 10]
descending_ordered_amounts = [19, 18, 16, 15, 10]
cumsum = [19, 37, 52, 68, 78]
threshold = 55
cumsum > threshold # [False, False, False, True, True]
```

Then I would like to get Ids = [0,4]

What would be the fastest way to get that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is to sort the ids along the values so you know what to return.
It can be done by something like this, using a intermediate value to hold a tuple of amounts and ids.

```
orderIds = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
amounts = [15, 18, 19, 16, 10]

des = [(x, y) for x, y in zip(amounts, orderIds)]
des.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)

sortedIds = np.array([x[1] for x in des])
threshold = 55
ids = np.cumsum([x[0] for x in des]) > threshold

print(sortedIds[ids])
```

that will print the ids that satisfy the requirement. i did not use a variable descending_ordered_amounts, since it is stored on the first column of des, so i just used a list comprehension in cumsum